# How to write class in javascript file

Tags: javascript, excel, angular, class, import

I get the JSON data from the excel file with a class in JavaScript and I'm going to create that class and my data will be printed on the screen with HTML. Most of what I wrote didn't work. I get an error when I type the JavaScript class and create the object.

```
class ExcelModal {
    name : string;
    id : string;
    constructor(id, name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
function  ExcelToJSON () {
    var list = new ExcelModal();
    document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
    this.parseExcel = function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: "binary"
            });
            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                // Here is your object
                var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
                list = JSON.parse(json_object);

                console.log( list );
                jQuery().val( json_object );

                list.forEach( function (obj){
                    $('#id).append('<input name="accesories" type="checkbox" value="'+obj.id+'"/> '+obj.name+'<br/>');
                });
            })
        };

        reader.onerror = function(ex) {
            console.log( ex);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };

};
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
    xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) *"I get an error"* Always copy-and-paste the **exact** error, and say where in the code the error is raised. Also describe what you've done to understand the problem.

Comment: what is your `json_object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You might have using Typescript with angular. Please ensure that you are passing only 2 arguments to an instance of `ExcelModal` class.

If you are using JavaScript, just remove *ExcelModal* class properties `id` & `name` (Refer ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349648/class-properties-must-be-methods-expected-but-instead-saw/51349783)*** for ***why?***), so your JS class would be like -

```js
class ExcelModal {
    constructor(id, name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

let em = new ExcelModal(1, 'abcd');
console.log(em.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExcelModal` require 2 parameters when it initializes

```
var list = new ExcelModal('id', 'name');
```